# Regex selectively include separator

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to find strings between two regex patterns. The tricky part is that parts of the "before pattern" need to be included in the output string.

Here is a simplified version of my code

```py
import re
start_pattern = "( StartString1 | StartString2 | StartString3ShouldBeIncluded | StartString4ShouldBeIncluded )"
end_pattern = "( EndString1 | EndString2 )"
joined_pattern = f'{start_pattern}(?P<content>.*?){end_pattern}'

input1 = "...somejunk ... StartString1 THECONTENT EndString1 ...somejunk ... "
output = re.search(joined_pattern, input1).group('content')
print(output)  # Prints 'THECONTENT' which is what I want

input2 = "...somejunk ... StartString3ShouldBeIncluded THECONTENT EndString2 ...somejunk ..."
output = re.search(joined_pattern, input2).group('content')
print(output)  # Prints 'THECONTENT' but I want 'StartString3ShouldBeIncluded THECONTENT'
```

Any way to change this regex to get the output I wish?

Comment: Is using two distinct regex an option? Because it seems like it would make for a more maitainable solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the start strings that should be included their own named group, and join the two named groups after the match. Since the start strings that should be included may not match and become a `None`, you can use the `or` operator to default the value to an empty string before joining with the `content` group:

```
import re
start_pattern = "( StartString1 | StartString2 |(?P<start> StartString3ShouldBeIncluded | StartString4ShouldBeIncluded ))"
end_pattern = "( EndString1 | EndString2 )"
joined_pattern = f'{start_pattern}(?P<content>.*?){end_pattern}'

input1 = "...somejunk ... StartString1 THECONTENT EndString1 ...somejunk ... "
match = re.search(joined_pattern, input1)
output = (match.group('start') or '') + match.group('content')
print(output)  # Prints 'THECONTENT' which is what I want

input2 = "...somejunk ... StartString3ShouldBeIncluded THECONTENT EndString2 ...somejunk ..."
match = re.search(joined_pattern, input2)
output = (match.group('start') or '') + match.group('content')
print(output)  # Prints 'StartString3ShouldBeIncluded THECONTENT'
```

Comment: Any way to capture both StartString3ShouldBeIncluded and StartString4ShouldBeIncluded without defining a group for each? Thanks for the answer btw

Comment: Glad to be of help. Doesn't my example already do that? Notice how the `start` group includes both StartString3ShouldBeIncluded and StartString4ShouldBeIncluded.

Comment: You are correct! I didn't notice it when porting from the answer to my code. Everything works brilliantly

Answer (score 0):

Just move the location of your group name as follows:

```
import re

start_pattern = "( StartString1 | StartString2 | StartString3ShouldBeIncluded | StartString4ShouldBeIncluded )"
end_pattern = "( EndString1 | EndString2 )"
joined_pattern = f'(?P<content>{start_pattern}.*?){end_pattern}'

input1 = "...somejunk ... StartString1 THECONTENT EndString1 ...somejunk ... "
output = re.search(joined_pattern, input1).group('content')
print(output)  # Prints 'THECONTENT' which is what I want

input2 = "...somejunk ... StartString3ShouldBeIncluded THECONTENT EndString2 ...somejunk ..."
output = re.search(joined_pattern, input2).group('content')
print(output)  # Prints 'StartString3ShouldBeIncluded THECONTENT'
```

Which prints:

```
 StartString1 THECONTENT
 StartString3ShouldBeIncluded THECONTENT
```